# How to create a countdown timer in android? Keeps restarting when button is clicked

Tags: android, button, timer, countdowntimer

I want to add a timer to my game. I am not entirely sure how to do that. I am newer to android coding. The game has to do with clicking a button within a certain amount of time. I have the counter working how I like it, but am having issues adding a countdown timer.

The timer should run for 30 seconds and I'd like it to display Seconds:Milliseconds which I am unsure of as well.

I tried creating this once before and had the counter and timer added, but the other issue I was running into was that I only had 1 button on the game screen which needs to start the timer and count, but the last time I did this, every time I would click the button, the timer would start over and keep counting at the same time from the previous click.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd also love a short explanation on such if possible as well.

Heres my code so far:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity
{
    int score = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        /** This is the score calculator */

        final ImageView startgametitleImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.startgameImage);
        final TextView currentScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gameScore);
        currentScore.setText("");
        final Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                score++;
                currentScore.setText("Score: " + score);
                currentScore.setTextSize(40);
                currentScore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                startgametitleImage.setImageDrawable(null);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private TextView txtCount, textViewTimer;
private Button btnCount, btnRestart;
int count = 0;
boolean[] timerProcessing = { false };
boolean[] timerStarts = { false };
private MyCount timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnRestart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    textViewTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    timer = new MyCount(10000, 1);

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // start timer once when button first click
            if (!timerStarts[0]) {
                timer.start();
                timerStarts[0] = true;
                timerProcessing[0] = true;
            }

            if (timerProcessing[0]) {
                count++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        }
    });
    btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timerProcessing[0] = true;
            count = 0;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            timer.cancel();
            timer.start();
        }
    });
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
        timerProcessing[0] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + ":"
                + millisUntilFinished % 1000);

    }
}
```

Here your counter varibale is replaced with a inner class so that you dont need to create counter variable each and every time. Just create once counter variable and call start method of it if you want to restart the counter.

Comment: Thanks! It definitley shows the timer I'd like, but the counter is not going up anymore. The timer also keeps restarting afer I click the button again. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry about that. new to this. Thanks again!